# Warning: DocumentRoot * does not exist on Centos 6

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, centos-6

My virtual hosts lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.com.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I apache restart `(sudo apachectl -k stop)` get this error:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/www/docs/example.com] does not exist
```

I've checked some ways:

All files and directories permissions is OK, everything 755.
I think, maybe this error about SeLinux and disable it. But not working. Still same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The directory /www/docs/example.com definitely exists?

Comment: Not exist. Created this directory by manuel but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `.` symbol. Try this instead:

```
DocumentRoot /www/docs/example\.com
```